# How to repeat observations n times in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, repeat

I am working on incorporating a variable that is recorded once per unit to a yearly dataset. While it is quite straightforward to repeat the observations n times, I have trouble assigning years to the observations.

The structure of my data is as follows:

```r
id startyear endyear dummy
1  1946      2005    1
2  1957      2005    1
3  1982      2005    1
4  1973      2005    1
```

What I want to do is to create a new row, called `years`, which repeats unit 1 `n = 2005 - 1946 = 59` times; unit 2 `2005-1957` times, and so forth as well as assigning the year, generating the following output:

```r
id startyear endyear dummy year
1  1946      2005    1     1946
1  1946      2005    1     1947
1  1946      2005    1     1948
1  1946      2005    1     1949
[…]
```

I have attempted to use `slice` and `mutate` in dplyr, in combination with `rep` and `seq` but neither gives me the result I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `map2` to create a sequence from 'startyear' to 'endyear' for each element into a `list` and then `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(year = map2(startyear, endyear, `:`)) %>%
    unnest
# id startyear endyear dummy year
#1    1      1946    2005     1 1946
#2    1      1946    2005     1 1947
#3    1      1946    2005     1 1948
#4    1      1946    2005     1 1949
#5    1      1946    2005     1 1950
#6    1      1946    2005     1 1951
#7    1      1946    2005     1 1952
#...
```

---

Or do a group by 'id', `mutate` into a `list` and `unnest`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(year = list(startyear:endyear)) %>% 
  unnest
```

Comment: Creative, a bit better than the concocted `merge`/`*_join` I was considering.

Comment: The latter method works perfectly, thanks! However, I am getting multiple warnings that say ```In startyear:endyear : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used```. Any way to work around this?

Comment: @VLarsen  I am not get any warnings with the example you posted.  Can you show another exampe

Answer (score 4):

Less elegant alternative, almost as simple:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    uncount(endyear - startyear + 1, .id = "row") %>%
    mutate(year = startyear + row - 1)
```